# Loading pretrained model for MobileNetv2 FasterRCNN in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, caffe, pre-trained-model

I have pretrained model for MobileNetV2. The variables of pretrained model are shown in the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n354egcueedxbjc/pretrained.txt?dl=0).

My model to be fine tuned needs the following variables.

```
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/depthwise/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/expand/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/expand/weights] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_15/project/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_16/depthwise/biases] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [MobilenetV2/expanded_conv_16/expand/biases] is not available in checkpoint
```

I can't find those in the pretrained models.

Which variables are most appropriate for those?

Comment: Depends on how you defined you model. Add some code

Comment: @Sharky My MobileNetV2 is as defined in Tensorflow's Object Detection API. `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet/mobilenet_v2.py'.